# Vuepress multiple sidebar don't show all items

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

I'm learning about vuepress and i'm trouble to config the sidbar.

### Description

Following the [docs I replicated the multiple-sidebar configuration](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#multiple-sidebars) without success.

Only the first path it is showed. What am i doing worg?

### My config js:

```
module.exports = {
  title: "Jhonatan Morais",
  description: "Welcome to my documentation site",
  editLinks: true,
  smoothScroll: true,
  themeConfig: {
    sidebar: {
      "/foo/": ["", "one"],

      "/bar/": ["", "three"],

      // fallback
      "/": ["" /* / */],
    },
  },
  postcss: {
    plugins: [require("autoprefixer"), require("tailwindcss")("./tailwind.js")],
  },
};
```

### My project organization

[image]

### My render results from yarn docs:dev

[image]

### Some others details

- If i browse the pages by url they are there
- Here is my system info:

Environment Info:

```
  System:
    OS: Windows 
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.16.2 - C:\Users\JHONAT~1.MOR\AppData\Local\Temp\yarn--1593443655966-0.6783257365479927\node.CMD
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - C:\Users\JHONAT~1.MOR\AppData\Local\Temp\yarn--1593443655966-0.6783257365479927\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.9.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  npmPackages:
    @vuepress/core:  1.5.2
    @vuepress/theme-default:  1.5.2
    vuepress: ^1.5.2 => 1.5.2
  npmGlobalPackages:
    vuepress: Not Found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is working as designed. You will only see the `/foo/` sidebar when the route starts with `/foo/`. So, you won't see the `/bar/` sidebar until you go to a route/page that starts with `/bar/`. You may want to use [Sidebar Groups](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#sidebar-groups) if you want to group links together in a single sidebar that is displayed for every route.

Comment: Oh. now I get the idea. Thank you I can't see this from docs explanation.